# Salesforce enterprise Edition - Login action link missing in Users in Manage Users->Users. How to login as other user?

Tags: user, custom, login

I am using the 30 days free trial, and I am trying to login as other users in enterprise edition using Login action link in Manager Users --> Users page. But i did not find the link except the Edit action link . How to login as other users and verify the functionality and features and simulate to see how it behaves? Is there any other alternate way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Your users usually have to give you permission to log in. Have them go to Setup / My Personal Information / Grant Login Access. In some cases, like Page Layouts, you can simulate the view of a user by profile, but login access often helps with diagnosing specific errors. Once you have a Sandbox, you can use the Login link on any user in the Sandbox. I don't believe trials get Sandboxes, though.

Comment: The Login link is not automatically enabled for all users in Sandboxes, it has to be requested from Salesforce support. Source: I had to do it about 3 weeks ago.

Comment: I've not had to do that process, I simply skimmed the general docs on it. It probably should be a default feature for new Sandboxes, because it's useful.

Comment: I agree that it should be on by default, I was surprised when it wasn't. I've since created another sandbox for the first time and it was not enabled there either.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot as any user in the Sandbox (or any environment) unless you ask Salesforce support to enable the **"Enables Org Admins to log in as any user without having access granted by the users"** permission on your Org.

You can then turn the feature on by going to **Your Name** > **Setup** > **Security Controls** > **Login Access Policies** > **Administrators Can Log in as Any User**. Once that is done you should have the Login action link available for all users.

Otherwise you can ask the individual users to grant you login access by going to **Your Name** > **My Personal Information** > **Grant Login Access**.

**EDIT:**
As of Summer '15 the "Administrators Can Log In As Any User" feature will be available in all Orgs by default. No need to ask support to enable it!

> After the Summer '15 release, administrators will no longer have to open a case with Customer Support to activate the "Administrators Can Log In As Any User" setting. Any administrator with the "Manage Users" permission will be able to control the setting directly from their org. Note: The setting will be set to "OFF" by default; administrators will still need to enable it. When this setting is enabled, administrators can log in as any user in their organization without asking end-users to grant login access.